# Tensorflow and keras: Problem with custom layer and model.fit related to (None,H,W,C) tensor

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras-layer, tensorflow2.0

Good morning!
I have searched the questions already asked but haven't found any regarding my problem but I have missed a relevant question, please post the link and I will look there.

First off: I'm using python 3.7.3 and tensorflow 2.0.

I want to write a custom flattening layer where I want the channel index to be the slowest varying index along the flattened data. There probably are better ways to do this, but my approach includes getting the number of channels, height, and width the following way:

```
def call(self,input):
        np_input = np.array([input]) 
        input_shape = np.shape(np_input)
        numChan = input_shape_sq[-1]
        numBatch = input_shape[0]
        width = input_shape[1]
        height = input_shape[2]
```

and then manually loop through the channels and flatten each image and then append them to a single vector.

This works fine when I'm sending images through “manually” but when I call model.fit it seems that it firstly sends through a tensor of shape (None,28,28,1) (I will use MNIST data, thus 28 by 28) which throws an error "IndexError: tuple index out of range".

So my question is how to deal with this, and more generally, what do you need to think about when making custom layers through manipulation of numpy arrays?

More explicit code:
I made a minimal (I think) example of where the code breaks:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class simple(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(simple, self).__init__()

    def build(self,input_shape):
        super(simple,self).build(input_shape)
        pass

    def call(self,input):
        np_input = np.array([input]) 
        input_shape = np.shape(np_input)
        numChan = input_shape[-1]
        numBatch = input_shape[0]
        width = input_shape[1]
        height = input_shape[2]
        return input
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import simpleLayer

mnist = keras.datasets.mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

train_labels=keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels=keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels)

train_images=train_images.reshape(len(train_images),28,28,1)
test_images=test_images.reshape(len(test_images),28,28,1)


train_images = train_images/255.0
test_images = test_images/255.0


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    simpleLayer.simple(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

test = model(train_images[0:10])
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images,train_labels,epochs=1,verbose=2)
```

Comment: (I’m not using tf2 yet so this comment is based on TF1). You have to use the tensorflow versions of those numpy functions, probably permute followed by flatten. It is important to remember that the tensorflow graph is not sequentially executed like a python script. Instead the python script defines the graph and it is run highly efficiently by some underlying c library. So you can’t just insert some numpy instructions into the layers, everything has to be tensorflow instructions so they form part of the graph.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, altough I would prefer if it were possible to convert to and from numpy without breaking the .fit() dunction. 

I have not found any good resource for tensorflow graphs for tf2, I've only seen graphs mentioned when talking about tf1. Do you have any suggestion where I could look up on this? Also, are there a list of implemented numpy-functions or do you suggest using "tf.numpy_function()"?

Do you know why model.fit first sends a tensor of shape (None, H,W,C) through the model?

Comment: After looking a bit I think that what to do is possible but I need to use slice assignment as in numpy: finalTensor[ i , a : b ] = otherTensor. The problem is that I can't wrap my head around scatter_nd and how to make assignment to a subset of an axis. The documentation isn't very useful. Any tips regarding this?

Comment: The graph is the backing object that contains all the tensors joined together. In the early days before keras you would create a graph (eg a neural network) by joining tensors together, then run that network by feeding in inputs and getting back the outputs. Keras abstracts this somewhat, but I believe underneath it all it is the same. All the operations in the graph are compiled C code with cuda acceleration etc.

Comment: Some tensorflow math operations are here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math

Comment: In you example, inputs is not modified by the call function so Im not clear what you wanna do, but if I interpret correctly you want to put the channels first before flattening so that it is the slowest varying dimension. There is a Keras layer “Permute” that should do this, or use tf.transpose when operating directly on tensors in the call function. By the way you can skip having to subclass layer by using a Lambda layer if you like.

Comment: Also for slicing, indexing, add, subtract etc, you can just write it as you would a normal numpy array, eg a = b[:,1:3], as tensorflow will automatically convert that into the appropriate tf.slice, tf.add, tf.subtract commands etc. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice

Comment: Thank you for the permute, I will look into that. :)
My problem isn't extracting from a tensor using slice but assigning values to a tensor in a "slice-way".

Comment: No worries.  It is hard to follow a bit - at the moment the call method in your custom layer just returns input unchanged? Also what is this line supposed to do: test = model(train_images[0:10])

Comment: This custom layer was a minimal example to recreate the error. I have solved the slicing problem and it's completely within tensorflow's functions. I can send you the custom layer in chat. (Which apparently exists...)

 test = model(train_images[0:10]) is meant to test if data can be sent through the model manually and it works while the model.fit() breaks.

Thank you for your time!